# Handling Overflow

Tags: programming, error-trapping

I have a notebook which takes in a user-defined function and starting value and tracks the orbit of the particle under iteration of the function. The problem occurs when the user enters a starting value with an orbit that goes to infinity.

```
f[x_]:=x^2;
x=1.1;
```

I get the error message:

> General::ovfl:

How can I catch this?

Comment: Look up `Check[]`.

Comment: It would be nice to have more details about what you are doing. If you're iterating a polynomial, for example, there's a simple bound on the absolute value of the iterate, beyond which, you are guaranteed the orbit will diverge to Infinity. It's easy to incorporate this into a loop or a `NestWhileList`. One issue with `Check` is that the `Overflow[]` won't be detected until after it happens. That's *way* too late, if you're working with compiled code.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on how you are doing the iteration. For example, if you were using `Nest`, then it could be replaced by `NestWhile`. If you are willing to modify the function, the you can explicitly test for divergence in the function, for instance

```
  f[x_] := Clip[x^2, {-1000, 1000}]
```

will bound `f`. If it is a user defined function, then you can wrap it in the `Clip` or define it using `Piecewise`:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, Abs[x] < 1000}, {1000, x >= 1000}, {-1000, x <= 1000}}]
```

Again, you might place the user-defined function in the first position and have the upper and lower limits always be fixed to catch the divergence. Perhaps more elegant is to use a conditional function definition:

```
f[x_] := x^2;
f[x_ /; x > 1000] := 1000
f[x_ /; x < -1000] := -1000
```

In this case, you can have the user define the function as before, but you also have the explicit divergence criteria predefined. Of course you might use more sensible numbers than "+/-1000"!

Comment: Thank-you! I've got some code to clean up.

Comment: +1, especially for the conditional function definition approach.